# Create an array of object from given array key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I have array like this .

```
const test = [
    { student: { id : '1', Name: 'A' }, marks: {  id: '2', Name: 'B' } }, 
    { student: {  id : '3', Name: 'C' }, marks: { id: '4', Name: 'D' } }
]
```

Now, from this array of object , I am trying to create two diff arrays which will be having seperate student and marks keys .

```
const student = [{"student":{"Id": {value: "A"}}}, {"student":{"Id": {value: "B"}}}]
```

and for marks

```
const marks = [{"marks":{"Id": {value: "C"}}}, {"marks":{"Id": {value: "D"}}}]
```

SO, Here what I tried is

```
test.map((index,item) => {
    return [item.student] 
  })
```

can any one help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, this is "bad practice" (Especially when you working with databases like MongoDB) to start changing the data structure and nesting + property names (`id` to `Id`) without a lot of meaning -or- semantic. In your case before change `console.log(test[0].student.id)` (return `1`). After `console.log(student[0].student.Id.value)` (Return `A` and not `1`).

Answer (score 4):

You want a new object returned, not a sub array.

Following uses destructuring to simplify the returned object

```js
const test = [
    { student: { id : '1', Name: 'A' }, marks: { id: '2', Name: 'B' } }, 
    { student: { id : '3', Name: 'C' }, marks: { id: '4', Name: 'D' } }
]

const students = test.map(({student}) => ({student}))
const marks = test.map(({marks}) => ({marks}))

console.log(students)
console.log(marks)
```

Comment: yes this one will work but I have to add new property as well, in this which will be value rather than id, and Name.

Comment: and also How do I return both of the new objects from the same map function.

Comment: just to make my nswer simple in a comment, use another map(). Or create the two arrays nd then use `forEach()` and push each object to associated array

Comment: As for other properties `...map(({student}) => ({student, someProperty: someValue}));`

Comment: So, this will remove the existing values and add the new property right

Comment: It creates a new object that you are adding properties to

Comment: thanks for the answer. Tried the. ...map but it throws compile time errror. Could you please add in answer, It would be greate help

Comment: Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)
Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?
when I used ...map

Comment: @ganeshkaspate you have to try `test.map` not `...map`.